# Python - Detect character and display if character is found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to code my program where if the user inputs just 1 or a integer that contains 1 as in 2431 is inputted a message would be displayed. The problems I'm having is that the program won't display the message back to back, as if the user inputted 1 twice. And the program is not detecting the 1 if the input is 3115, in which it should.

```
   one = False  
   guess = input('Enter A Four Value Integer With Different Values Except for 1: ')
    while guess in (1,'1'):
        print('No ones are allowed')
        one = True
        break
```

Comment: Your current setup is checking whether `2431` is in `1`, which it clearly cannot be; in other words the logic is back-to-front. Also, there's no need for checking against `1` since `input` will always give back a string.

Comment: `guess` is also outside of the `while` loop so if you ever _did_ trigger it, the user does not get prompted to have another guess. Can you clarify the expected behaviour of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
contains_one = True
guess = '1'
while '1' in guess:
    print('No ones are allowed')
    guess = input('...')
```

You had the right idea with using a while loop, but since you put a `break` at the end it would only do one iteration. As said in the comment, the `input` should be in the loop to be redefined if the condition is not satisfied.

Here we initialize guess outside of the loop to be able to "go into" the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using python's `input` function, it's value is `str` type.

so you can try like this:

```
if_1 = lambda :True if '1' in input('value?: ') else False
while if_1():
    print('No 1 is allowed!')
else:
    print('Great!')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest solution I can think of:

```
while True:
    guess = input('Number with no 1s: ')
    if '1' in guess:
        print("No ones are allowed.")
    else:
        break
```

If you don't need the error message you can simplify the code a bit:

```
guess = '1'
while '1' in guess:
    guess = input('Number with no 1s: ')
```